# How do I patch a Rails 2.1 project with new vulnerability fixes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I've got an old Rails project with frozen Rails 2.1. I need to apply the patch from here http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/9/4/xss-vulnerability-in-ruby-on-rails/

Using git-am doesn't work, I'm guessing because its expecting the git repo to have the rails folders in the root, which it doesn't. So how do I apply this patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, next step was to try

```
$ cd vendor/rails 
$ git apply <name-of-patch>
```

No luck with that (nothing happens). Then tried

```
$ cd vendor/rails 
$ patch -p1 < <name-of-patch>
```

which worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Stinks they've got it in some git format, instead of a normal patch.

A few ideas:

1) the instructions on that site say to use git-apply not git-am (so maybe git-apply would work?)

2) you might be able to turn it into a normal patch by just deleting the lines at the top, so what's left is a normal patch. i.e. so the file stars with:

```
--- a/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte.rb
+++ b/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte.rb
```

3) If that doesn't work, you could clone the git repo/revision/branch the patch was meant for, and apply it to that, then use git-diff to get a normal patch, which you could then apply to your site (with the "patch" command, not git)